# Earning Bux by fully stocking levels?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Usually, when you fully stock a level, you get a coin bonus. But for a couple of times I have earned a complimentary Bux. Does anyone know, what are the conditions for recieving it?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean getting bux from fully stocking levels? i thought your items sold faster when fully stocked and nothing else? and i am up to 35 levels

Comment: There's not a note that pops up to tell you but you do randomly get Bux when stocking levels completely.  If you've ever looked at your Bux count and thought it seemed high... that's probably why.

Comment: @Catija There's a note.  Look above, I've added a pic.

Comment: @Esq Occasionally when you fully stock, you will get a pop-up telling you you've earned a bonus of 1 Bux.  Look at the pic above.

Comment: interesting, i will keep an eye for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is random. There is no rhyme or reason to it.

Comment: It's also extremely rare.  I've received a Bux as a bonus once out of literally hundreds of opportunities.